# My system doesn't boot up anymore

Tags: boot, updates

I update my system today and a few minutes after the update was done, my system started to fall apart.

Everything began with icons of the window controls not showing up anymore. Further I could start any applications anymore as if they weren't installed. *Wingpanel* and *plank* were closed and not startable from the terminal, too.

I tried to restart my computer, but it's stuck on the elementary logo.
On recovery mode I can boot however.

Never had an issue like this before, so no idea what to do about it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Pressing `Esc` while the elementary OS logo is displayed should give you some messages about what's going on. But by what you're saying, it could be a failing HDD, so, from recovery, try running fsck on your drive.

Answer (score -2):

I have never had your problem so I cannot really do much to help you, but try this.

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

I found this as a suggestion on reddit when I had long boot times. This sped it up, so I guess it is worth a shot.